# Erro de Operador Logico Javascript em página JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, apache

Tenho um pagina JSF aonde utilizo o primefaces. Quando utilizo o operador logico em minhas funções javascript, ele exibe este problema: o nome da entidade deve seguir imediatamente o '&' na referência da entidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar escapar as entidades XML.

```
<h:outputText value="Tom &amp; Jerry" />
```

Este problema não está relacionado com o JSF em si, mas com a tecnologia de visualização, você precisaria garantir que o modelo é bem formado XML e que todos os carácteres especiais que devem ser representados como é, foram escapados como acima.

Lista de entidades de caracteres predefinidos que precisam ser escapados no XML sempre que você gostaria de exibi-los. São as seguintes entidades de caracteres:

```
"     &quot;
&     &amp;
'     &apos;
<     &lt;
>     &gt;
```

Comment: Eu não quero Exibi-los. Eu quero comparar duas situações em javascript: if (operador1 && operador2) { // Faça alguma coisa }

Comment: Não é só para exibi-los, mas tb em ternários dentro da interpolação do JSF ou primefaces. Atualize sua questão com os trechos de código relevante por favor. E mesmo dentro de bloco js, se a extensão do arquivo for xhtml a solução é essa. Você testou @LuizFelipe?